# How to draw queue with draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I want to draw the following image with draw.io (it is about system modelling, e.g. M/M/1 etc.).

[image]

My problem is that I cannot draw the queue. How would you do this? Of course, I could create it with several rectangles but this is not elegant.

Answer (score 1):

click more shapes at end and enable rack and cabinets where you will find set of insert formats

Comment: Thanks but I still do not find symbols for the queue even in the rack or cabinets.